# TypeScript: An abstract class is undefined while creating a child class (Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined)

Tags: typescript, web, webpack

I have built a framework called "tyframe" as monorepo using lerna. (https://github.com/tyframe/tyframe) Currently there are the two packages "core" and "example". The latter is indended for demonstration pruposes and works as expected.

Now I want to use the package "@tyframe/core" in a different web project without success.

**The problem:**

My class App inherits from the class AbstractApplication, but on runtime AbstractApplication is undefined and I get the error "Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined".

To demonstrate the problem and to make it understandable, I have created a minimal example on Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-av2uka?devtoolsheight=33&file=index.ts

Is there anything else to consider when I publish my framework so that I can use it in other web projects?

**Futher information:**

I am using webpack to build my framework:

```
module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          use: {
              loader: 'ts-loader',
              options: {
                  configFile: 'tsconfig.build.json',
              }
          },
          exclude: /node_modules/,
        },
      ],
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: [ '.ts', '.js' ],
    },
  };
```

No errors are thrown during the compilation process.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I believe you need to include the built files in your published module (i.e, dist folder). See this tutorial https://medium.com/cameron-nokes/the-30-second-guide-to-publishing-a-typescript-package-to-npm-89d93ff7bccd

Comment: My index.ts file exports all files of core package and webpack build me an index.js file, which contains all the code of the package. The definition files are also created and published. In my opinion I have followed all points of the instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution.

@mbdavis was right! (See comment)

I built my core package with webpack, which compiled all files to es5 and bundled them into one file (index.js). But for each source file a separate js file must exist, in the dist folder.

So I changed the build process and used the Typescript compiler directly.

I have made all necessary changes in the following commit: https://github.com/tyframe/tyframe/commit/c0820361fa23ceab9428c1a5c7def7a4d0faf1bc

**Dist folder for changes:**

[image]

**Dist folder after changes:**

[image: dist_folder_after_changes]